# How to pass npm package lodash as a DI in angular js for angular-google-maps using browserify?

Tags: angularjs, npm, browserify, lodash, angular-google-maps

I am using `npm` as a package manager for my angular application and `Browserify` to include the libraries.
I am using the angular-google-maps package : http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps

I am getting :

```
ReferenceError: _ is not defined
    at o (vendor.js:8)
    at Object.load (vendor.js:8)
    at $get (vendor.js:8)
    at Object.r [as invoke] (vendor.js:1)
    at vendor.js:1
    at i (vendor.js:1)
    at Object.r [as invoke] (vendor.js:1)
    at p.instance (vendor.js:2)
    at m (vendor.js:2)
    at a (vendor.js:1)
```

as error.

Now this how I include the js files :

```
require('lodash');
require('angular-simple-logger');
require('angular-google-maps');
```

And this is how I inject them in the angular.module :

```
var requires = [
        /*What to inject here?*/
        'nemLogging',
        'uiGmapgoogle-maps',
];

angular.module('mapApp',requires);
```

What to include in the  controller  :

```
angular.module('mapApp').controller('mapController', 
    function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi, /*What to pass here?*/){
});
```

Please guide as to what to inject in the angular app and what parameter to pass to my angular app to get rid of this error?

Comment: It seems your error is related to `lodash`. not related to `angular-google-maps`

Comment: But I need it because angular-google-maps service has lodash as a dependency.

Comment: You can use it globally. Just include it in page.

Comment: Sadly the application coding practice requires js files to be only included via browserify and not via <script> tags. So I can't do that.

Comment: Hi @jackOfAll. I'm currently trying to get angular-google-maps working with browserify as well. I'm wondering if you'd be able to share your full example? I'm unable to get it working and a full working example could help a lot.

Comment: Hi @Matt : This is the way I initialize angular google maps via browserify :http://plnkr.co/edit/Zy2FP6gWv8P8bVL6w4si?p=preview . This code snippet demonstrates how to initialize your angular app via browserify with the necessary angular-maps dependencies. Rest of the steps you can follow as their official documentation suggests. I am sorry can't create a working copy in plunkr. I don't know how to use node modules in plunkr :(. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @jackOfAll. I really appreciate you sharing the minimal example. Unfortunately it still doesn't work in my environment. 

If I attempt to require maps/logging in my main JS file and pass the require'd modules to the angular.modules constructor, the angular lifecycle seemingly does not begin.

I wonder if there is something about your browserify config that differs from mine?

Regardless, thanks for your example. I may need to post a separate topic here if I can't figure this out on my own soon.

Comment: Actually I was just able to get it to work.. Difference for me was in how I passed the dependencies array to the angular.module constructor. Instead of passing a reference to the require'd module (as in the plunkr above), I had to require the modules but then pass an array of strings to angular.module:

var requires = ['nemLogging', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps'];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `angular-google-maps` module doesn't inject lodash using angular DI, but assumes that lodash is available globaly. Make lodash global by adding it to the window object:

```
window._ = require('lodash'); // this will add it to the global namespace
require('angular-simple-logger');
require('angular-google-maps');
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is:

```
angular.module('mapApp', requires)
     .value('_', _);
```

That should now mean that you can do:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('mapController', function ($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi, _) {

});
```

So here is a working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sx0Ons9rVnKGfLWAYCdK?p=preview) of it. It may be something else that you're doing wrong.

Comment: I tried your solution out but the same error seems to persist.

Comment: try changing `value` to `service`

Comment: you are requiring it on the page that your assigning it to a value?

Comment: Yeah I am requiring it on the same page where I am assigning it to a value.

Comment: @jackOfAll I've updated my answer with a working plnkr to give you a reference to make sure everything matches up.

Comment: @jackOfAll also make sure that you are not minifying the angular output without making sure that you are properly decorating your functions.

Comment: Thanks for your plnkr implementation. But, the solution provided by Ori Drori was more convenient to implement for my situation. Nevertheless, thanks for taking interest in my problem.